# automize wkwebview double click

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I use a wkwebview and display a captcha in a view controller. the captcha display is to small, but with a double click it align automatically. how can I automize that.

[image]

I try this with the wkwebview delegate.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("")
    webView.scrollView.zoom(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), animated: true)
}
```

But it align is not correct.

greetings

[image]

Comment: you can use this ReCaptcha  http://blog.flaviocaetano.com/ReCaptcha/

Comment: thanks but this is only for Invisible reCAPTCHA

Comment: the captcha is implemented and works. Only the screen align is incorrect

Comment: ok , please add you'r html file without sitekey i need this file for test

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this script in your html file

```
<head><title>Captcha</title><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script><script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
     var RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY = 'YOUR_KEY';
     var RECAPTCHA_THEME = 'dark';

     var PAGE_BG_COLOR = '#222';

     function waitReady() {
     if (document.readyState == 'complete')
     documentReady();
     else
     setTimeout(waitReady, 100);
     }

     function documentReady() {
     while (document.body.lastChild)
     document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastChild);

     var div = document.createElement('div');

     div.style.position = 'absolute';
     div.style.top = '50%';
     div.style.left = 'calc(50% - 151px)';

     document.body.style.backgroundColor = PAGE_BG_COLOR;
     document.body.appendChild(div);

     var meta = document.createElement('meta');

     meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
     meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0');

     document.head.appendChild(meta);

     showCaptcha(div);
     }

     function showCaptcha(el) {
     try {
     grecaptcha.render(el, {
                       'sitekey': RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY,
                       'theme': RECAPTCHA_THEME,
                       'callback': captchaSolved,
                       'expired-callback': captchaExpired,
                       });

     window.webkit.messageHandlers.reCaptchaiOS.postMessage(["didLoad"]);
     } catch (_) {
     window.setTimeout(function() { showCaptcha(el) }, 50);
     }
     }

     function captchaSolved(response) {
     window.webkit.messageHandlers.reCaptchaiOS.postMessage(["didSolve", response]);
     }

     function captchaExpired(response) {
     window.webkit.messageHandlers.reCaptchaiOS.postMessage(["didExpire"]);
     }

     waitReady();
     })();

    function captchaSolved(){alert("working");}</script></head><body><form action="?" method="POST"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="captchaSolved" data-sitekey=""></div><br/><div class="g-recaptcha-response"></div></form></body>
```

Comment: Hey the captcha display correct but my delegate don't call now. have you any idea?

Comment: func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        completionHandler()
        
        
    }

Comment: it doesn't work but the captcha display perfect. I miss the event after success

Comment: please make sure use `WKUserContentController didReceive` delegate